# What is causing browser lag / lock up when trying to set multiple states on one message request to websocket via React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, coinbase-api

My code currently renders a table that pulls data from a websocket object and renders it conditionally on each row based on `id`. There is a live price and a 24 open price that is retrieved from the message object, both that are being used to make realtime price change data available. My `.onmessage` code works fine, but setting two states (`setprice` and `setdailystats`) seems to overload the browser and starts to cause lag / lock up. Please help identify if there is a memory leak or something similar in the code below that would cause this type of behavior.

ProductRow.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const usePrevious = (value) => {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
      ref.current = value;
    });
    return ref.current;
  };

export default function ProductRow(props) {
    const [pricecolor, setpricecolor] = useState({});
    const prevPrice = usePrevious(props.price);
    const curPrice = props.price;
    // changes the text to red or green to indicate price gain or loss
    useEffect(() => {
        if ( prevPrice > curPrice){
            setpricecolor('pricedown');
        }
        if ( prevPrice < curPrice) {
            setpricecolor('priceup');
        } 
    }, [curPrice, prevPrice]);

    return (
        <tr>
            <td><p>{props.id}</p></td>
            <td><p className={ pricecolor }>{props.price}</p></td>
            <td><p>{(props.dailystats - curPrice).toFixed(2)}</p></td>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

Watchlist.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Button, Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ProductRow from "./ProductRow";

export default function WatchList() {
  const [currencies, setcurrencies] = useState([]);
  const [price, setprice] = useState({});
  const [isToggle, setToggle] = useState();
  const ws = useRef(null);
  const url = "https://api.pro.coinbase.com";
  const product_ids = currencies.map((cur) => cur.id);
  let first = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    ws.current = new WebSocket("wss://ws-feed.pro.coinbase.com");

    let pairs = [];

    const apiCall = async () => {
      await fetch(url + "/products")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => (pairs = data));
      
      let filtered = pairs.filter((pair) => {
        if (pair.quote_currency === "USD") {
          return pair;
        }
      });

      filtered = filtered.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.base_currency < b.base_currency) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a.base_currency > b.base_currency) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
      
      setcurrencies(filtered);
      first.current = true;
    };
    apiCall(); 

  }, []);

  const [dailystats, setdailystats] =useState('');
  useEffect(() => {

    ws.current.onmessage = (e) => {
      if (!first.current) {
        return;
      }
      let data = JSON.parse(e.data);
      if (data.type !== "ticker") {
        return;
      }
      // retrieve current price for id and set it to 'price' state
      setprice(prev => ({ ...prev, [data.product_id]: parseFloat(data.price).toFixed(3)}));
      // retrieve the opening daily price for id and set it to 'setdailystats' state  
      setdailystats(prev => ({ ...prev, [data.product_id]: parseFloat(data.open_24h).toFixed(3)})); 
    };
  }, [price, dailystats]);
  const handleToggleClick = (e) => {

    if (!isToggle) {
      let msg = {
        type: "subscribe",
        product_ids: product_ids,
        channels: ["ticker"]
      };
      let jsonMsg = JSON.stringify(msg);
      ws.current.send(jsonMsg);
      setToggle(true);
      console.log('Toggled On');
    }
    else {
      let unsubMsg = {
        type: "unsubscribe",
        product_ids: product_ids,
        channels: ["ticker"]
      };
      let unsub = JSON.stringify(unsubMsg);
  
      ws.current.send(unsub);
      setToggle(false);
      console.log('Toggled Off');
    }
  };
  return (

    <div className="container">
      <Button onClick={handleToggleClick}><p className="mb-0">Toggle</p></Button>
      <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Symbol</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Price Change</th>
          <th>% Change </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {currencies.map((cur) => {
        return <ProductRow key={cur.id} id={cur.id} price={price[cur.id]} dailystats={dailystats[cur.id]}></ProductRow>
      })}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import WatchList from "./components/Watchlist";
import "./scss/App.scss";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <WatchList></WatchList>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Of interest in creating a live snippet https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/125981

Comment: Try to isolate the websocket part from the react parts perhaps so you can say for sure which part is where the challenge lies

Comment: I was looking through React's hook documentation and came across this page https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

do you think that this might be a better option?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).